# Which Code-Versioning tool is being used by Microsoft-Azure for its project management

Tags: html, azure, github, azure-devops

I know there are 3 `Source-Controll Tools` - Git (github, bitbucket, etc.) / SVN / Mercurial.

Now, I know there is a *Project Management Tool* called *Microsoft Azure*.

I want to know how MS-Azure manages its *Code Versioning Tool*. Does it have any 4th type of tool (for its platform) or it uses any 1 of the above options?

I am pretty new to *MS Azure Devops*, So I don't have any idea!

Also: Kindly let me know are **MS Azure** and **MS Azure Devops** - one and the same thing? Or Not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Azure is a online cloud service which you can use to create Virtual machines , applications and run any type of service without worrying about the hardware .

Azure Devops is a product from Microsoft which can help you with continuous Integration and delivery of your software product. Earlier we used to have Teams foundation Server (TFS) in on-premise which provided some of the similar functionalities as Azure Devops. However , now we have renamed the same product and enhanced it with an online offering called Azure Devops. You can use Azure devops as Project Management tool.

Code versioning or version control is built within Azure Devops and it provides two types of version control . Internally we use azure devops for managing products and a mix of both TFVC and Git for code versioning.

- Git :- [Distributed Version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/get-started/what-is-repos?view=azure-devops#git)
- Team Foundation Version Control : [Centralized version Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/get-started/what-is-repos?view=azure-devops#tfvc)

I hope the above should clarify your query. You can also view the detailed documentation around the [Azure Devops product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops) . Should this be helpful , do accept it as answer. In case of further queries , please reply in comments.

Comment: Do you maybe know the answer for this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096837/azure-pipeline-custom-task-with-an-unknown-number-of-inputs